# Mysql query for fetching information from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have below 3 tables from where i need to fetch information.
nagios_performance_data
nagios_large_performance_data
client_circuit_mapping

Below are the sample data from those tables,

```
nagios_performance_data
 circuit_name               | record_date         | latency | packetloss |
+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+------------+
| Device 1                  | 2016-11-28 04:40:00 |   72.54 |       0.00

nagios_large_performance_data
+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+------------+
| circuit_name               | record_date         | latency | packetloss |
+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+------------+
| Device 1                   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |   83.00 |       0.00 |
+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+------------+

client_circuit_mapping
+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| circuit_name                  | groupname                             |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Device1                       |Group1                                 |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Now I need to query these three tables for getting the below output,

client_circuit_mapping.groupname,  nagios_performance_data.circuit_name, nagios_performance_data.record_date, nagios_performance_data.packetloss, nagios_performance_data.latency,  nagios_large_performance_data.latency

Can anyone help me with the query to get this output

Comment: have you ate least tried something? Can we see some SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `join` these three tables with `circuit_name`:

```
select 
    c.groupname,
    a.circuit_name,
    a.record_date,
    a.packetloss,
    a.latency,
    b.latency
from nagios_performance_data a
join nagios_large_performance_data b on a.circuit_name = b.circuit_name
join client_circuit_mapping on a.circuit_name = c.circuit_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables based on the `circuit_name` column:

```
SELECT A.*, B.group_name, C.latency large_latency FROM nagios_performance_data A
INNER JOIN client_circuit_mapping B ON B.circuit_name = A.circuit_name
INNER JOIN nagios_large_performance_data C ON C.circuit_name = A.circuit_name
```

Notice that I use an alias for the `nagios_large_performance_data.latency` column.